# Prove $\frac{1}{2}\int |p - q| d\nu = 1 - \int \min(p, q)d\nu$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $P, Q$ be probability measures and $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ such that $P \ll \nu$ and $Q \ll \nu$, i.e. absolutely continuous. Then we denote $p = \frac{dP}{d\nu}, q = \frac{Q}{d\nu}$.

I am trying to prove an identity $$\frac{1}{2}\int |p - q| d\nu = 1 - \int \min(p, q)d\nu$$

It is a bit confusing because $\int\min(p, q)d\nu = \int\max(p, q)d\nu = 1$ due to the fact $\int p d\nu = \int dP = 1$ and $\int q d\nu = \int dQ = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{\omega: p(\omega)>q(\omega)\}$, $A^c=\{\omega: p(\omega)\leq q(\omega)\}$. Then 
$$\int |p - q| d\nu =\int_A|p - q| d\nu +\int_{A^c} |p - q| d\nu =
\int_{A}p\,d\nu - \int_{A}q d\nu+\int_{A^c}q\,d\nu - \int_{A^c}p d\nu.
$$
Substitute
$$
\int_{A}p\,d\nu = 1- \int_{A^c}p\,d\nu \quad\text{and}\quad \int_{A^c}q\,d\nu = 1- \int_{A}q\,d\nu.
$$
Obtain 
$$\int |p - q| d\nu = 2-2\int_{A^c}p\,d\nu-2\int_{A}q d\nu = 2-2\int \min(p,q)\,d\nu.
$$

Note also that in general $$1\neq\int\min(p, q)\,d\nu \neq \int\max(p, q)\,d\nu \neq 1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does it mean that, in general, $\int\min(p, q)d\nu \ne \int p d\nu$ when $p < q$ ?

Comment: It is impossible that $p(\omega)<q(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ since both functions should integrate to $1$. Consider any two simple p.d.f.'s. Say, $\Omega=[0,1]$, $p(x)=2x$, $q(x)=1$, $\nu$ is a Lebesgue measure. Then $\min(p,q)(x) = 2x$ for $x\in[0; 0.5]$ and $\min(p,q)(x) = 1$ for $x\in(0.5; 1]$. This is not p.d.f. at all, and it integrates to $3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** $$\frac{1}{2}\int |p - q| d\nu = 1 - \int \min(p, q)d\nu$$

**Proof:**

Note that $$\min(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}+\min\left(a-\frac{a+b}{2},b-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)=\frac{a+b}{2}+\min\left(\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$$ $$\implies \min(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{|b-a|}{2}$$

Thus:

$$\int \min(p, q)d\nu=\int \left(\frac{p+q}{2}-\frac{|p-q|}{2}\right)d\nu=1-\int \frac{|p-q|}{2} d\nu$$

as $\int p d\nu = \int q d\nu=1$. Rearranging then admits the result.